# boost::apply_visitor is not a member of [some] class

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, visitor-pattern, boost-variant

I have a ShapeType, Point, with some coordinates, (1,2), and I'd like to use apply_visitor in an overloaded operator () to add the coordinates (3,4) to my Point, so that Point ends up being (4,6). Where is my implementation failing? I think my ShapeVisitor class is correct, but I am getting an error, "apply_visitor" is not a member of CLARK::Point.

Code is as follows.

```
#include "Point_H.hpp"
#include "Shape_H.hpp"
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

typedef boost::variant<Point,Line,Circle> ShapeType;

ShapeType ShapeVariant(){...}

class ShapeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<> 
{
private:
    double m_dx; // point x coord
    double m_dy; // point y coord

public:    
    ShapeVisitor(double m_dx, double m_dy);
    ~ShapeVisitor();

    // visit a point
    void operator () (Point& p) const
    {
        p.X(p.X() + m_dx);
        p.Y(p.Y() + m_dy);
    }
};

int main()
{   
    using boost::variant;

    ShapeType myShape = ShapeVariant(); // select a Point shape

    Point myPoint(1,2);

    boost::get<Point>(myShape) = myPoint; // assign the point to myShape

    boost::apply_visitor(ShapeVisitor(3,4), myPoint); // trying to add (3,4) to myShape

    cout << myPoint << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are missing the include (*Edit*: doesn't seem to be required anymore)

   ```
   #include "boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp"
   ```
2. Also instead of

   ```
   boost::get<Point>(myShape) = myPoint;
   ```

   You'll just want to do

   ```
   myShape = myPoint;
   ```

   Otherwise, if the variant did not actually contain a `Point` yet, you'll receive a `boost::bad_get` exception
3. Finally

   ```
   boost::apply_visitor(ShapeVisitor(3,4), myPoint);
   ```

   should have been

   ```
   boost::apply_visitor(ShapeVisitor(3,4), myShape);
   ```

A simple self-contained example that shows all these points would look like this:
(See it live on **http://liveworkspace.org/code/33322decb5e6aa2448ad0359c3905e9d**)

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp"

struct Point { int X,Y; };

typedef boost::variant<int,Point> ShapeType;

class ShapeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<> 
{
private:
    double m_dx; // point x coord
    double m_dy; // point y coord

public:    
    ShapeVisitor(double m_dx, double m_dy) : m_dx(m_dx), m_dy(m_dy) { }

    void operator () (int& p) const { }

    // visit a point
    void operator () (Point& p) const
    {
        p.X += m_dx;
        p.Y += m_dy;
    }
};

int main()
{   
    Point myPoint{ 1,2 };

    ShapeType myShape(myPoint);
    boost::apply_visitor(ShapeVisitor(3,4), myShape);

    myPoint = boost::get<Point>(myShape);
    std::cout << myPoint.X << ", " << myPoint.Y << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
4, 6
```

Comment: Indeed, including "boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp" does not change the functionality. This is a significant change, though:

`boost::apply_visitor(ShapeVisitor(3,4), myShape);`

Now I get an error, "error C2664: 'void ShapeVisitor::operator ()(CLARK::Point &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'T1' to 'CLARK::Point &'"

Is it a problem with the ShapeVisitor members?

Comment: @Clark likely, yes. In my sample, note that the `operator()(int&) const` overload is _required_ for the visitor to compile. In short, you need an overload that matches _every_ type in the variant. You'll find out why the use of `boost::get` was also critically wrong when you _run_ the compiled code :)

Comment: My problem was that I didn't yet have an overload that matched every type in the variant. Now I've created them (empty, like your overloaded operator for int), and I'm running into dreaded LNK errors!

"Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ShapeVisitor::~ShapeVisitor(void)" (??1ShapeVisitor@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main" and "Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ShapeVisitor::ShapeVisitor(double,double)" (??0ShapeVisitor@@QAE@NN@Z) referenced in function _main". These have always been tough for me to figure out.

Comment: @Clark see my sample again: you need to implement the functions you declare in ShapeVisitor. If you do, refer to [what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/) for help in finding the solution there. It is really not that complicated. You'll get it soon enough :)

Comment: That's what I meant. In particular, I added this:
"void operator () (Line& lp) const { }" and this "void operator () (Circle& cp) const { }". Those are my only other ShapeTypes. That got me a lot further, but I ran into this new linker error. I'm checking the thread you provided right now.

Comment: @Clark I meant, you are missing the _definition_ (body) for the ShapeVisitor constructor/destructor (at least during the linking step). This is what the linker error refer to. And the linked answer explains more in depth